# Setting text-overflow ellipsis for a float left div or list

Tags: css-float, css

Here's what I'd like to do:

- Create a list that only takes up as much room (horizontally) as needed (i.e. as the longest list element.
- When the list doesn't fit on the page, trim the list text and show an ellipsis.

I use a combination of `white-space:nowrap` and `text-overflow:ellipsis`. It works fine for a normal list, but in that case the list takes up the full width of the page.

To force it to only take as much space as needed I applied a `float:left`, but this breaks the text-overflow.

Example:

```
<ol style="border:1px solid red;font-size:100px;">
    <li style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">Long list item. Ellipsis works.</li>
</ol>

<ol style="float:left;border:1px solid red;font-size:100px;">
    <li style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">Float left list. No ellipsis here.</li>
</ol>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/73M7G/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because a floating element does not inherits the size from its container,

you need to specify the width:; to < ULs > too!

http://jsfiddle.net/73M7G/3/

test with width:100%;

another test
http://jsfiddle.net/73M7G/6/

Comment: super because a floating element does not inherits the size from its container,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make the list an inline-block, see it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/73M7G/4/