# Text overflow ellipsis for list items and keep numbers

Tags: html, css, html-lists

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7678728/483779) is a spin-off of this issue. I am using the technique illustrated in the answers given, but I wish to retain the numbers at the beginning of the `ol li`, with the HTML/CSS I have:

```css
ol.songlist > li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}
.songlist > li > a {
  width: 125px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<ol class="songlist">
  <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a></li>
</ol>
```

The numbers (1., 2., 3., etc.) are not longer visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display block is preventing the numbers from showing. Place the list-style-position: inside; on the li element

```css
ol.songlist > li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
   list-style-position:inside;       
}

.songlist > li > a {
   width: 125px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<ol class="songlist">
   <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a></li>
   <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a></li>
   <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a></li>
   <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a></li>
   <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: this answer was mostly correct.  I needed to retain the display: block, on the  anchor, but add display: list-item on the li.  The links are all displaying perfectly if they are too long, retaining their numbers and still floating. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`LI` is `display:list-item;` by defaut. This `display` value produces the numbers or circle, square,...

If you reset `li` to `block`, then there is no more `list-item` to show.

```css
ol.songlist > li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  /* display: block;*/
}
.songlist > li > a {
  width: 125px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<ol class="songlist">
  <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="linktoURL">Song Title</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```